# Angular- kendoGrid not show data until change Input value(filter)

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, datagrid

I have a question, I use Metronic and KendoUI(DataGrid).
I'm trying to fetch data from API. It's all works fine, but... When I recieve the data, DataGrid, not show the results until I change the value from Input (filter for all columns).

I hope it's for the state of the table... somebody knows how to achieve/fix it?

This is my TypeScript

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataBindingDirective } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
import { process, State } from '@progress/kendo-data-query';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { EntidadesService } from './entidades.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'kt-prefirma-entidades',
  templateUrl: './prefirma-entidades.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./prefirma-entidades.component.scss']
})
export class EntidadesPreFirmaComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private entidadesService: EntidadesService) {}
  @ViewChild(DataBindingDirective) dataBinding: DataBindingDirective;
  public gridData: any = this.fromAPI();
  public gridView: any[];
  public gridState: State = {
    sort: [],
    skip: 0,
    take: 10
  };
  public editDataItem;
  public isNew: boolean;
  public mySelection: string[] = [];

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    //   this.fromAPI();
    this.gridView = this.gridData;
  }
  public onFilter(inputValue: string): void {
    this.gridView = process(this.gridData, {
      filter: {
        logic: 'or',
        filters: [
          {
            field: 'nombreEntidad',
            operator: 'contains',
            value: inputValue
          },
          {
            field: 'codEntidad',
            operator: 'contains',
            value: inputValue
          },
          {
            field: 'division',
            operator: 'contains',
            value: inputValue
          },
          {
            field: 'codigoDivision',
            operator: 'contains',
            value: inputValue
          },
          {
            field: 'personaAsociada',
            operator: 'contains',
            value: inputValue
          }
        ]
      }
    }).data;

    this.dataBinding.skip = 0;
  }

  fromAPI() {
    this.entidadesService.get().subscribe(entidades => {
      this.gridData = entidades;
    //   this.onFilter('asd');
    });
  }
  public onStateChange(state: State) {
    this.gridState = state;

    // this.editService.read();
  }

  public addHandler() {
    // this.editDataItem = new Product();
    this.isNew = true;
  }

  public editHandler({ dataItem }) {
    console.log(dataItem);
    this.isNew = false;
  }

  public cancelHandler() {
    this.editDataItem = undefined;
  }

  public saveHandler(product) {
    // this.editService.save(product, this.isNew);

    this.editDataItem = undefined;
  }

  public removeHandler({ dataItem }) {
    // this.editService.remove(dataItem);
  }

}
```

And the HTML:

```
<kendo-grid [kendoGridBinding]="gridData" 
 (dataStateChange)="onStateChange($event)" [kendoGridSelectBy]="'id'" [selectedKeys]="mySelection" [pageSize]="20" [pageable]="true" [sortable]="true" [groupable]="false" [reorderable]="true" [resizable]="true" [height]="480" [columnMenu]="{ filter: false }">
 <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate>
    <input placeholder="Search in all columns..." kendoTextBox (input)="onFilter($event.target.value)" />
    <button kendoGridExcelCommand type="button" icon="file-excel" style="float:right;">Export to Excel</button>
    <button kendoGridPDFCommand icon="file-pdf" style="float:right;">Export to PDF</button>
</ng-template>

     <kendo-grid-messages pagerPage="Página" pagerOf="de" pagerItems="ítems" pagerItemsPerPage="ítems por página">
     </kendo-grid-messages>
     <ng-template kendoGridToolbarTemplate [position]="'top'">
         <div class="col-md-2">
             <button kendoGridAddCommand [icon]="'plus'" [primary]="true" class="arnal-btn-primary new-btn btn-block float-left">
         Nova Entitat
       </button>
         </div>
     </ng-template>
     <kendo-grid-column field="nombreEntidad" title="nombreEntidad"></kendo-grid-column>
     <kendo-grid-column field="codEntidad" title="codEntidad"></kendo-grid-column>
     <kendo-grid-column field="division" title="division"></kendo-grid-column>
     <kendo-grid-column field="personaAsociada" title="personaAsociada"></kendo-grid-column>

 npm
     <kendo-grid-command-column title="command" width="220">
         <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate>
             <button kendoGridEditCommand [primary]="true">Edit</button>
             <button kendoGridRemoveCommand>Delete</button>
         </ng-template>
     </kendo-grid-command-column>
     <ng-template kendoPagerTemplate let-totalPages="totalPages" let-currentPage="currentPage">
         <kendo-pager-prev-buttons></kendo-pager-prev-buttons>
         <kendo-pager-numeric-buttons [buttonCount]="10"></kendo-pager-numeric-buttons>

         <kendo-pager-info></kendo-pager-info>
         <kendo-pager-next-buttons></kendo-pager-next-buttons>
         <kendo-pager-page-sizes [pageSizes]="[5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 'Tots els registres']"></kendo-pager-page-sizes>
     </ng-template>
 </kendo-grid>

 <kendo-grid-edit-form [model]="editDataItem" [isNew]="isNew" (save)="saveHandler($event)" (cancel)="cancelHandler()">
 </kendo-grid-edit-form>
```

Thanks in advance
Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You fetch the data asynchronously so after the data is received and you update the grid with it, you need to tell the change detector to check for changes.

You do this by adding this to your code:

1. Add the change detector injection to your constructor

   ```
   constructor(private entidadesService: EntidadesService, private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
   ```
2. Ask the change detector to check for changes:

   ```
   fromAPI() {
       this.entidadesService.get().subscribe(entidades => {
           this.gridData = entidades;
           //   this.onFilter('asd');

           // Ask the change detector to check for changes at the earliest convenience
           this.changeDetector.markForCheck();
       });
   }
   ```